# Using untyped leaflet with angular 8 causing problems

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I dont want to use @ts-ignore every where, i instead declared a module L in a seperate ts file with needed types, everything works fine in build, but it crashes in test and it says

`error TS2686: 'L' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`

```
declare module L {
  // plugins that extend Class i.e L.MyClass
  export let WFS: any;
  export let Filter: any;
  // export type WFS;

  // plugins that uses class factory i.e myClass
  // export let myClass: any;

  // plugins that extend Control comes here i.e L.Control.Navbar
  export namespace Control {
    export let Search: any;
  }
  // plugins that have control factories come here i.e. L.control.navbar
  export namespace control {
    export let groupedLayers: any;
  }

  // plugins that extend Layer comes here i.e L.Layer.NewLayer
  // export namespace Layer {
  // export let NewLayer: any;
  // }
  // plugins that have layer factories come here i.e. L.layer.newLayer
  // export namespace layer {
  //   export let newLayer: any;
  // }
  // plugins that extend Handler comes here i.e. L.Handler.NewHandler
  // export namespace Handler {
  //   export let NewHandler: any;
  // }
  // plugins that have handler factories come here i.e. L.Handler.newHandler
  // export namespace handler {
  //   export let newHandler: any;
  // }
}
```

And my component is like:

```
import 'leaflet';
import '../my_typings.ts';
import 'leaflet-wfst/dist/leaflet-wfst.src.js';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(L as any) worked as charm....

Answer (score 1):

missing specific L import, try adding

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```